# Can I auto calculate float values passed into a multiline textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to make a multiline textbox be able to auto calculate values (float, decimals, int) which are passed into a multiline textbox. users are able to passed the value inside the textbox, and it will auto calculate the values. I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks without any success. The only part I managed to solved is storing the list of values in a multiline textbox.

```
<!--aspx file-->
<asp:TextBox ID="textTotal" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
Width="336px" Height="150px" OnTextChanged="textTotal_TextChanged"> 
</asp:TextBox>

<!--c# back end-->
protected void chk_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
           GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(chk.NamingContainer);
           int index = row.RowIndex;
           for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != index)    
    ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Checkbox1")).Checked = false;
        }
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            textArea.Text += row.Cells[1].Text + "\n";
            textTotal.Text += row.Cells[3].Text + "\n";


        }
        else
        {
            textArea.Text = string.Empty;
            textTotal.Text = string.Empty;


        }



    }
```

my project is that users can select rows from a gridview and the values will be passed on to the texboxes. The textArea.Text was supopsed to store the array of items stored in row.cells[1] to users. The textTotal.Text, was supposed to received and calculate the sums of all the item's prices which are stored in the row.cells[3] however the values just shows as a list like in the textArea.Text. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: just a silly question but, are you sure you are doing `5 + 5 = 10` and not `"5" + "5" = "55"`?

Comment: i dont see any conversion you should make to add up floats. Convert your texts to float first ...

Comment: @haroon, how do I make the conversion so it will enable float calculation?